# PC with short-lived RTC battery - how to immediately time-sync on boot and avoid time jumps

Tags: startup, ntp, clock

I've got a 64-bit Intel PC running Debian 8 with a capacitor-based clock, which means after 3 days without power the time is lost from the hardware clock. To help work-around this, I was thinking we could use a nearby computer on the LAN (with a better battery-backed RTC) to act as a local NTP server.

On  boot, will the PC be able to perform an NTP sync fast enough that by the time the "normal" applications start up (esp. our user applications) they are using the correct time, and we aren't dealing with time discontinuities? Our primary function is data logging, so if we started a log file as 1970 and then had it leap to 2016 that would be catastrophic.

Comment: You can also look at the raspberry pi board, which has no RTC. It uses the `fake-hwclock` package to save/restore a reasonable time in a file, until ntp syncs up.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things you should do.  Make sure `ntpd` is started as early as possible in the boot sequence, and put an `ntp-wait` somewhere in the boot sequence before any of your applications start.

Depending on your version of Linux, how you achieve that will vary.  You should, however, make your application startup dependant on the `ntp-wait` finishing.

`ntp-wait` simply waits for the `ntpd` daemon to report it is synced.

The right way to do this on Debian 8 would be to configure `systemd`, and to add a new service for the `ntp-wait`, which your applications would then be dependant upon.

The easy way to do it, is put an `ntp-wait` in the startup scripts for your apps.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the low-quality question, I've tried to fix it up. I'm running Debian 8. I'll give this a shot!

Comment: No worries, updated my answer.  If you need more help on sorting out the systemd stuff, I'm not your man, someone else will need to expand on that 'proper' approach.  Me, I'd just cheat and stick the `ntp-wait` in your startup scripts.